# Kendo Grid Filter Row kendoDropDown not working first time selection

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

Can someone explain me why I can't use this type of filter for the new kendo version (2015).

http://jsbin.com/janopoqeqe/1/edit?js,output

I can see that the ddl is loaded but when I select one of the element in the DDL for City, it doesn't change the grid. I wouldn't mind to keep using the previous version, but i would love to understand if there is something that I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

--

Update 1:

I opened a ticket here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-filter-row-kendodropdown-not-working-first-time-selection-for-version-2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I agree with you. Even on their [demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization) there is the same problem.
You might create a new post on their form.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use an internal version of Kendo UI.

See their reply: http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-filter-row-kendodropdown-not-working-first-time-selection-for-version-2015#tBMI_kMSxEChwElwGqmarQ